# getelementbyid().length undefined?

Tags: c#, javascript

I have this code in C#:

```
 @foreach (var photo in photos){
            <div class="comment1" id="many">
             @photo.name
            </div>
}
<input type="button" name="button" onclick="count()" />
```

And I want to know how many "photo.names's" there are, so I made this javascript

```
function count(){
var algo = document.getElementById("many");
alert(algo.length);
}
```

But for some strange reason it gives me "**undefined**". Why is it happening?
*I have the javascript on a separate file*

Comment: First and formost you cannot have multiple elements on a page with the same `id`.

Comment: Also, **getElementById** starts with a lower case g

Answer (score 3):

> Why is it happening?

HTML elements do not have a `length` property. If you're looking for the length of what the element contains you'd need to do this

```
document.getElementById("many").innerHTML.length;
```

Keep in mind that IDs should be unique to an element.

If you're looking for "how many" comments there are, you'd need to do the following

```
document.getElementsByClassName("comment1").length;
```

Classes don't need to be unique across elements and and element can have more than 1 class.

Answer (score 1):

[`document.getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById), as the method name suggest, gets a *single* element, not multiple.

Ids in HTML are supposed to be *unique*; there should be only one element with an id. So `getElementById` returns exactly that element.

If you want to mark multiple items, you should use a class name instead. You can then use [`document.getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName).